# Java Lang Error OSGI bundle

Tags: java, swing, osgi, jgraph

I have to implement an old peace of code as an OSGI bundle apparently this old code heavily depends on swing components even though I have included all of the swing dependencies to bundle manifest I still get the following exception, which is caused by `jgraph`, jgraph.jar is also included as a run time dependency. I am not very sure what is the problem. Any help will be appreciated

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Cannot load com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initializeDefaultLAF(UIManager.java:1351)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(UIManager.java:1459)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(UIManager.java:1426)
    at javax.swing.UIManager.getDefaults(UIManager.java:659)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:662)
    at org.jgraph.JGraph.setUI(JGraph.java:792)
    at org.jgraph.JGraph.updateUI(JGraph.java:806)
    at org.jgraph.JGraph.<init>(JGraph.java:767)
    at org.jgraph.JGraph.<init>(JGraph.java:721)
    at org.jgraph.JGraph.<init>(JGraph.java:697)
    at org.processmining.plugins.declareminer.visualizing.DGraph.<init>(DGraph.java:35)
    at org.processmining.plugins.declareminer.visualizing.ModelView.<init>(ModelView.java:37)
    at org.processmining.plugins.declareminer.visualizing.AssignmentModelView.<init>(AssignmentModelView.java:43)
    at ee.ut.deviance.preprocessing.DeclareDevianceModelGenerator.generateModel(DeclareDevianceModelGenerator.java:405)
    at ee.ut.cs.rum.declare.deviance.miner.plugin.v2.factory.RumPluginWorkerImpl.runWork(RumPluginWorkerImpl.java:177)
    at ee.ut.cs.rum.declare.deviance.miner.plugin.v2.Activator.start(Activator.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
```

Comment: Did you: 1) look for the AquaLookAndFeel jar file and include it? or 2) edit the code to simply get rid of the requirement that AquaLookAndFeel be used?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As far as I recall, the OS X 'native' PLAF is `AquaLookAndFeel`. Even if it were technically possible to export it, this code would break Apple's code use terms for use on *nix and Windows based machines.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Unfortunately the code is heavily bundled with AquaLookAndFeel, the code base is quite huge and I don't have a full knowledge of it, isn't AquaLookAndFell part of the swing, if yes I have included all of the swing dependencies